# how do i add my prev/next btn to work in my script

Tags: javascript, html

[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qNPU.jpg)

```
 <div class="slider">
                <div class="slides">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio1">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio2">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio3">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio4">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio5">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio6">
<div>
```

```
                  <div id="next"><</div>
                    <div id="previous">></div>
```

```
                  <div class="navigation-manual">
                  <label for="radio1" class="manual-button"></label>
                  <label for="radio2" class="manual-button"></label>
                  <label for="radio3" class="manual-button"></label>
                  <label for="radio4" class="manual-button"></label>
                  <label for="radio5" class="manual-button"></label>
                  <label for="radio6" class="manual-button"></label>
                </div>
</div
```

```
  var counter = 1;
  setInterval(function()
  {document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
  counter++;
  if(counter > 6){
    counter = 1;
  }
}, 5000);
```

I want to add the button next/previous function to my slider but I'm confused about writing the code, does anyone want to help?

Comment: go through https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-image-slider-works-with-radio-button/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Please refer to below javascript link and it will work for you 100%.
```

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/9xdp4zqc/3/)

Comment: can comment rather in answer section link

Comment: :). Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Do like this and check,

```
<div id="next" onclick="nextClick()"></div>
<div id="previous" onclick="preClick()"></div>

function nextClick(){
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
    counter++;
    if(counter > 6){
        counter = 1;
    }
}

function preClick(){
    counter = counter - 2;
    document.getElementById('radio' + counter).checked = true;
    counter++;
    if(counter > 6){
        counter = 1;
    }
}
```

Remember `counter` variable is a global variable.